# See if your local.xml is disregarded or not

Tags: xml, layout

When editing my `local.xml`, if I make a syntax error the entire document is disregarded.
For example if I write:

```
<reference name="left">
    <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.vert" template="catalog/navigation/vert"/>
</block>
```

Ussualy I write a remove action in `<default>` to see if the block dissapears and the `local.xml` is parsed, but there must be a better way to see if this file is loaded properly.

Sometimes I think that my sintax is incorrect, but in fact there was an error previously and the entire document is diregarded. How can you check it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should work with Developer Mode on. This way, if there is something wrong in an XML you get an error message on the screen.

In order to enable developer mode, you can add this to `htppd.conf` (or corresponding files for other servers)

```
SetEnv MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE 1
```

Or simply edit `index.php` temporarily and replace this:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
}
```

with

```
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
```

Comment: Better solution (if index.php is in the repository and .htaccess isn't) is to edit the .htaccess with `SetEnv MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE`. This way you will be sure to not commit unwanted changes.